# Eclipse DataBinding: Delay model updates until dialog confirmation

Tags: eclipse, data-binding, jface

I have a TitleAreaDialog with default buttons where I use data binding to synchronize the model and the widgets. How do I delay model updates *until* the user clicks the 'OK' button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to delay. In another way, to register the DisposeListener to check the user select ok or cancel. If the result is not ok, I give up the changes.

In my case, I binded the model fetched from hibernate. Do hibernate persist when 'ok', do refresh model (re-read data from database) when cancel is pressed.

However, I want the function to delay or undo changes, too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `UpdateValueStrategy` of `POLICY_CONVERT` or `POLICY_ON_REQUEST` for your binding to 'delay' the model updates:

```
DataBindingContext dbc = new DataBindingContext();
final Binding binding = dbc.bindValue(target, model, 
    new UpdateValueStrategy(UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_CONVERT), null);
```

Then you can update the target via the OK button like this:

```
Button btnOK = mToolkit.createButton(parent, "OK", SWT.NONE);
btnOK.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
    {
        binding.updateModelToTarget();
    }
});
```

Or you can update all bindings within the `DataBindingContext` by calling `DataBindingContext.updateTargets()`